# How can I get biggest value for each name

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have the next table:

**name**:history

**columns**:

```
id(primary key),name,value
```

**values**:

```
1, dani, 50

2, dani, 100

3, john, 100

4, john, 150
```

How can I get for each name the biggest value he has, so the result will be:

```
2, dani, 100

4, john, 150
```

thanks!

Comment: Does the query need to work on both SQL Server and mysql?

Comment: +1 - @AdaTheDev - Not sure why this would be Both MySQL *and* SQL Server

Answer (score 5):

```
select max(id), name, max(value) from history group by name
```

Comment: This is wrong. You can't select max(id) because you are not grouping by ID. Also there is not point to group by ID because it's field with unique values.

Comment: This is not wrong - it will return the maximum id value for each name, which is what the OP requested. The sentence "You can't select max(id) because you are not grouping by ID." is utterly incorrect.

Comment: @MārisKiseļovs When selecting `max(id)`, grouping by ID is the last thing you should do! The result set will then have 1 record per `ID`, with `max(id)` being each ID

Comment: But this does assume that the values are always in ascending order.  I'd rather use row_number() or join on a max() lookup.

Comment: This would return ids that don't tie to the max(value) though, unless (as in the example) the values are in ascending order.

Comment: This would return the largest ID for the name, not necessarily the ID corresponding to the largest value for the name. The OP asked for "for each name the biggest value he has" - I understood this to mean the largest ID and the largest value for each name.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT id,name,MAX(value) FROM history GROUP By name;
```

Comment: Can the id be selected if it's not present in the GROUP BY clause?

Comment: @klennepette You can select any columns regardless to grouping.

Comment: @klennepette: Yes, in MySQL, although which value is returned is not guaranteed. (It tends to be the first accessed, so this query is likely to return id values 1 and 3 instead of 2 and 4.)

Comment: @klennepette AFAIK MySQL allows do that but result is bit unpredictable. In my opinion it's better to write queries explicitly.

Comment: @MarkBannister Ah yes MySQL, I overlooked that tag. Just for the record Microsoft SQL Server does not allow this I believe.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT id, name, value
FROM history h
JOIN (
    SELECT name, MAX(value) as value
    FROM history GROUP By name;
) t ON h.name = t.name and h.value = t.value
```

Answer (score 0):

There is one small nuance: when you will have the same value twice inside of the **name** group, you should not get this row twice.
Let us assume that if you will have the same value, last id should be returned:

```
  SELECT DISTINCT t2.MaxId, h.name, h.value
    FROM history h
    JOIN (
        SELECT name, MAX(value) as value
        FROM history GROUP By name
    ) t ON h.name = t.name and h.value = t.VALUE
    JOIN (
    SELECT MAX(id) MAxid,name,value FROM
    history
    GROUP BY name,VALUE
    ) t2 ON [t2].[name]=[h].NAME AND [t2].[value]=[h].value
```

But i strongly recommend to use on SQL Server one of window functions, for example `RANK`:

```
;    WITH   C
    AS     (SELECT H.id,
                   H.name,
                   H.value,
                   RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY value DESC, id DESC) 
                      AS [ValueRank]
            FROM   history AS H)
    SELECT c.id,
           name,
           c.value
    FROM   c
    WHERE  ValueRank = 1;
```

Last query has much better performance.

Comment: Exactly. Using RANK is the best way to go.  There's a good walkthrough of how RANK works here:  http://www.mikesknowledgebase.com/pages/SQLServer/Rank.htm

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id,
       name,
       MAX(value) 
FROM   history 
GROUP BY id,
         name
ORDER BY id
```

Comment: Operation **group by id** will return all rows because every id is unique.

Answer (score 0):

```
select T1.*  
from history as T1  
inner join (select MAX(value) as value,name  
         from history
         group by name) as T2
on T1.name = T2.name
and T1.value = T2.value
```